# DynamoDB update_item issue: "When calling the UpdateItem operation: The conditional request failed" (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am attempting to update an existing item in my Dynamo DB database based on 2 things: 1) extraction date and 2) item URL. However, I am receiving the "Conditional request failed" error.

I have implemented the code below; however, the error has continued to populate.

If helpful, my Primary Partition Key is "itemUuid (String)" (not primary sort key is used). Date is in the format "m/d/yyyy".

```
    if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200 :
        table_page1Update.update_item(Key={'itemUuid' : str(item['itemUuid'])},
                    UpdateExpression = 'SET readSuccess = :readSuccess',
                    ConditionExpression = 'extractionDate = :extractionDate AND itemUrl = :itemUrl',
                    ExpressionAttributeValues={
                        ':readSuccess' : 'OK',
                        ':itemUrl' : 'http://url_of_item_in_db_field.com',
                        ':extractionDate' : config.DATETIMEFOREXPORT
                    }
        )
```

I expect the readSuccess field to populate as "OK" for items matching the date and itemUrl.

Answer (score 0):

Might be interpreted in the wrong format by dynamo, have you tried the below (I made everything a string type including the date because dates are stored as strings in dynamo):

```
    if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200 :
        table_page1Update.update_item(Key={'itemUuid' : {'S' : str(item['itemUuid'])}},
                    UpdateExpression = 'SET readSuccess = :readSuccess',
                    ConditionExpression = 'extractionDate = :extractionDate AND itemUrl = :itemUrl',
                    ExpressionAttributeValues={
                        ':readSuccess' : { 'S':'OK' },
                        ':itemUrl' : { 'S':'http://url_of_item_in_db_field.com' },
                        ':extractionDate' : { 'S':config.DATETIMEFOREXPORT }
                    }
        )
```